# How to extract specific lines from a file and save specific lines into each new file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a file which contains following lines.In this I want to read the lines between line which startswith forw and the line before endswith .txt. copy each set of extracted lines into separate new files using python script.

```
forw l1tt DeleteULPhCH 0
forw l1tt activate 1
forw l1tt DeleteCCB 0 1 0
forw l1tt DeleteDLPhCH 0
BCH_CCB63.txt
DL_BCH_PhCh.txt
forw l1tt setuecontext 100
forw l1tt DeleteCCB 65 1 0
DL_BCH_PhCh.txt
```

My output should be like:

```
forw l1tt activate 1
forw l1tt DeleteULPhCH 0
forw l1tt activate 1
forw l1tt DeleteCCB 0 1 0
forw l1tt DeleteDLPhCH 0
```

in one file.

and in another file it should be like:

```
forw l1tt setuecontext 100
forw l1tt DeleteCCB 65 1 0
```

I used the following python code: It is extracting only the first set of output.But I cant able to extract second set of output after given the break condition.Please anyone help me soon.

```
fin=open("script.txt","r")
fout=open("output.txt","w")
lines=fin.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r"(.*)(.txt)",line):
           break
        print line
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that he does not want to include the '.txt' lines into the created files

```
import re
n = 1

with open("script.txt","r") as my_file:
  my_list = []
  for line in my_file.readlines():
    if not re.search(r"(.*)(.txt)",line):
      my_list.append(line)
      with open("output"+str(n)+".txt","w") as out_file:
        for item in my_list:
          out_file.write(item)
    else:
      if my_list:
        my_list=[]
        n += 1
```

Creates files:

```
$ cat output1.txt
forw l1tt DeleteULPhCH 0
forw l1tt activate 1
forw l1tt DeleteCCB 0 1 0
forw l1tt DeleteDLPhCH 0

$ cat output2.txt
forw l1tt setuecontext 100
forw l1tt DeleteCCB 65 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple naive state machine you can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


n = 0
output = []
state = 0  # 0 = start, 1 = forw

with open("foo.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if "forw" in line:
            state = 1
        if state == 1:
            output.append(line)
            if ".txt" in line:
                state = 0
                with open("{0:d}.txt".format(n), "w") as outf:
                    outf.write("\n".join(output))
                    outf.write(line)
                n += 1
                output = []
```

Which produces the following output files:

```
$ cat 0.txt
forw l1tt DeleteULPhCH 0
forw l1tt activate 1
forw l1tt DeleteCCB 0 1 0
forw l1tt DeleteDLPhCH 0
BCH_CCB63.txtBCH_CCB63.txt

$ cat 1.txt
forw l1tt setuecontext 100
forw l1tt DeleteCCB 65 1 0
DL_BCH_PhCh.txtDL_BCH_PhCh.txt
```

It's not quite exactly what you're after, but it's close.
Hopefully you can modify this to suit your needs.

State machines are very useful!

Comment: thank you so much.but i didnt understand with open("{0:d}.txt".format(n), "w") as outf: this line.....you didn't mention the "d" range.if {0:d}.txt then how the file names will come ??

Comment: It's pretty obvious from the sample output above. The output filenames will be ``0.txt``, ``1.txt``, ``2.txt``, ... ``N.txt``.